# How do i get readdir ignore directories in C/C++?

Tags: c++, file, directory, readdir

I am reading the content of the current library with `readdir`, but I would like to treat only files and not directories. How do I know that I am pointing to a directory and not to a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [lstat](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/lstat.html), and the [S_ISDIR](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html) macro.

E.g. without error-checking:

```
struct stat buffer;
int status;
char path[PATH_MAX];
DIR *dir = opendir(dir_name);
... 
struct dirent *de = readdir(dir);
sprintf(path, "%s/%s", dir_name, de->d_name);
status = lstat(path, &buffer);
if(S_ISDIR(buffer.st_mode))
{
   ...
}
```

EDIT: Fixed to include directory in lstat path (per el.pescado).  As noted by R Samuel Klatchko, you may want to take a whitelist approach (S_ISREG) instead of blacklisting types as they come up.

Comment: You have to combine dirname and filename before passing path to lstat, eg. do sprintf(path, "%s/%s", dir_name, de->d_name);

Comment: It would be a bit more robust to only process regular files entries (`S_ISREG`) rather then exclude directory entries (`S_ISDIR`).  That way, if you run across another type of entry you won't accidentally process it.

Comment: And just noticed something else.  You need to think about whether to use `stat` or `lstat`.  If you have a symlink to a real file, do you want to process it or skip it?  If you want to skip it, use `lstat` so you'll know it's a symlink.  If you don't care about it being a symlink and want to process it assuming it's a symlink to a regular file, use `stat`.

Answer (score 0):

```
`void DirectryNFileCount(const char * FileDir)
 {
  DIR *dir;
  int filecount;
  int dircount;
  struct dirent *direntry;
  if ((dir = opendir (FileDir)) == NULL) 
  {
   /*Error code*/
   } 
 while((direntry = readdir (dir)) != NULL)
 {
 if(direntry->d_type==DT_DIR)
 dircount++;
/*do something with directries      */
 }
 else 
 {
  filecount++;
  std::cout<<"Files Names"<<direntry->d_name<<std::endl; 
 }
 }
  std::cout<<"THIS Directory has "<<filecount<<" FILES and "<<dircount<< " DIRECTORIES";
}
```

Comment: A written explanation accompanying your code would make this answer more helpful.